# Compiling Multiple Less Files into CSS

Tags: css, less

I have been handed a project where they have been compiling LESS files into a css file which is being used for the site.

Is there a way to reverse engineer this? I have downloaded simpless and tried to compile all LESS files into the same CSS file but it just keeps emptying it.

Is there a way somehow to figure out how they have been doing it?

Comment: are you using a build tool like grunt or gulp?

Comment: Usually it's just one ("master") less file that includes/imports all other less files. This is the file you need to compile. And make sure to use some up-to-date compiler (The Less compiler included with Simpless is not one of those).

Comment: Is there any recommendation on a compiler for Mac?

Comment: I would use grunt. Or at least use the master LESS that has includes to the other LESS files so you only use the master to compile with.

Comment: I am trying to compile this - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/369a5930d3c16833e085 - but I keep getting this error:ParseError: Missing closing ')' in css/mixins.less on line `586, column 9:
585     .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
586       (~".span@{index}") {
587         .span(@index);`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest is to use third-party applications like: https://incident57.com/codekit/ or http://koala-app.com/. Just drag and drop your LESS files and click Compile!

Comment: Thanks, I have got Codekit on trial. However a fair few errors. No idea how people could have compiled this before :(

Answer (score -1):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Web Essentials extension and I modified the solution level "compilerconfig.json" file to map the multiple input-output files and it works for perfectly for my by compiling all of the input less files into css output files.

[image: Solution Level compiler options file]

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "css/styles.css",
    "inputFile": "css/styles.less"
  },
  {
    "outputFile": "multiselect-dropdown-lib/MultiselectDropdownStyle.css",
    "inputFile": "multiselect-dropdown-lib/MultiselectDropdownStyle.less"
  }
]
```

[image: Contents of the compiler options file]

*I re-read your question and I think you are looking for compiling all LESS files into a single CSS file. If that is the case, then my soloution is slightly differnt. It compiles all LESS files into corresponding CSS files.*